# Sorting a vector using lambda functions in winapi

Tags: c++, sorting, winapi, lambda, bitmap

I' making a program which allows the user to choose a .bmp from a folder and then displays the other pictures in the folder according to how similar they are to the selected image. As such I have created a function which compares two bitmaps and returns a score

```
double compareImages(HBITMAP pic1,HBITMAP pic2);
```

the higher the score the more similar the two pictures are.

I have also created a vector which holds the handles to the instances of every picture in the folder

```
std::vector<HBITMAP> pictures;
```

Now I want to sort the handles in the vector according to their score when compared to the selected picture. Higher score should come first.

```
std::sort(pictures.begin(),pictures.end(),[](const HBITMAP& pic1,const HBITMAP& pic2) -> bool 
{ 
double comp1 = compareImages(pic1,selectedPicture); //the score of pic1
double comp2 = compareImages(pic2,selectedPicture); //the score of pic2
return comp1>comp2;
}
);
```

getting an error:

```
||=== Build: Debug in imageComparator (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|

C:\Users\GS\Desktop\Programy\imageComparator\src\leftWindow.h||In function 'LRESULT WindowProcedureLeft(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)':|

C:\Users\GS\Desktop\Programy\imageComparator\src\rightWindow.h|133|warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11|

C:\Users\GS\Desktop\Programy\imageComparator\src\rightWindow.h|134|error: no matching function for call to 'sort(std::vector<HBITMAP__*>::iterator, std::vector<HBITMAP__*>::iterator, WindowProcedureRight(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)::<lambda(HBITMAP__* const&, HBITMAP__* const&)>)'|

C:\Users\GS\Desktop\Programy\imageComparator\src\rightWindow.h|134|note: candidates are:|

C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h|4676|note: template<class _RAIter> void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter)|

C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h|4676|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|

C:\Users\GS\Desktop\Programy\imageComparator\src\rightWindow.h|134|note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided|

C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h|4705|note: template<class _RAIter, class _Compare> void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare)|

C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h|4705|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|

C:\Users\GS\Desktop\Programy\imageComparator\src\rightWindow.h|134|required from here|

C:\Users\GS\Desktop\Programy\imageComparator\src\rightWindow.h|134|error: template argument for 'template<class _RAIter, class _Compare> void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare)' uses local type 'WindowProcedureRight(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)::<lambda(HBITMAP__* const&, HBITMAP__* const&)>'|

C:\Users\GS\Desktop\Programy\imageComparator\src\rightWindow.h|134|error:   trying to instantiate 'template<class _RAIter, class _Compare> void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare)'|
```

The important bits being probably:

```
C:\Users\GS\Desktop\Programy\imageComparator\src\rightWindow.h|134|error: template argument for 'template<class _RAIter, class _Compare> void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare)' uses local type 'WindowProcedureRight(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)::<lambda(HBITMAP__* const&, HBITMAP__* const&)>'|
```

what is wrong and what does

```
local type 'WindowProcedureRight(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)::<lambda(HBITMAP__* const&, HBITMAP__* const&)>
```

actually mean?

Comment: `comp1>comp2` should be `comp1<comp2` no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important bit is

> "C:\Users\GS\Desktop\Programy\imageComparator\src\rightWindow.h|133|warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11|"

You should turn C++11 functionality on using the compiler switch mentioned in the message.

Also, I imagine the comparison you are doing is likely going to be slow. It is probably wise to calculate all the image scores once, and then sort using the cached results.

Comment: oh, thank you. I've been starring into the screen for hours with no results and the fix proved to be so simple...